# Boundedness in $L^0$ space

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Suppose $L^0$ is the space of all real-valued random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and $C \subset L^0$. What does it mean for $C$ to be bounded in $L^0$?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. I understand the boundedness in Lp space which has the definition of norm. But  L0 space does not have the norm. 
So I want to see the exact definition of boundedness in L0 space.
Does it mean the integral of f  ∊C is finite?

Answer (score 1):

The definition I have seen in my course is the following. Recall that $L^0$ has a metric given by
$$d(f,g) = \min \{a | \mathbb{P}(|f - g| > a) \leq a\}$$
where we have fixed a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on the space -- I think you may need the space to be $\sigma$-finite to do this.

We then say that $C \subseteq L^0$ is $L^0$-bounded if for all balls $B_{\epsilon}$ of radius $\epsilon$ around 0 you can find some $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta C \subseteq B_{\epsilon}$.

As an edit, let me add that in this paper by Zitkovic https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.2730.pdf he does use a notion of boundedness in $L^0$. The notion he uses is called boundedness in probability, as discussed here http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~alen/articles/asymp-final.pdf . This notion is equivalent to the notion I have introduced above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have understood the definition of L0 boundedness.